# why anchor tag is dissappereing in tinymce editor?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

When I'm giving anchor tag inside div and outside some p tags, after clicking ok button why anchor tag is being remove. Why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Please provide what you have.. currently this question is unclear

Comment: Hi, is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable html verifying when you create your TinyMCE :

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    verify_html: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, to have a valid HTML, an inline-level element shouldn't be a container of a block-level element.

By default CSS, `<a>` tags have `display: inline;`, while `<p>` tags have `display: block;`.

One way to achieve what you are trying to do is to change all `<p>` to `<span>`, then give each `<span>` CSS style `display: block;`. Because `<span>` default display CSS is `display: inline;`

Comment: It's not true that an `<a>` tag cannot have block elements as childs. The [HTML documentation for the A tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) specifically states it can in an example. It can not have other interactive elements as child (e.g. other links or buttons) though.